# Made a simple calculator, need to add text so that when you input a non-number, it tells you that it's not a number

Tags: java

I made a really simple calculator for my Java assignment, but I am stuck on the part where I need to add text when the user inputs a non-number. What do I need to add to it and where do I need to add it to for it to work? I've tried multiple different ways that I searched on the internet but none of them seemed to work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char operator;
    double num1;
    double num2;
    double result;
    
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter operator (either +, -, * or /): ");
    operator= s.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.print("Enter number 1 and number 2: ");
    num1= s.nextDouble();
    num2= s.nextDouble();

    switch (operator) {

        // performs addition between numbers
        case '+':
            result = num1 + num2;
            System.out.print(num1 + "+" + num2 + " = " + result);
            break;

        // performs subtraction between numbers
        case '-':
            result = num1 - num2;
            System.out.print(num1 + "-" + num2 + " = " + result);
            break;

        // performs multiplication between numbers
        case '*':
            result = num1 * num2;
            System.out.print(num1 + "*" + num2 + " = " + result);
            break;
        // performs division between numbers
        case '/':
            result = num1 / num2;
            System.out.print(num1 + "/" + num2 + " = " + result);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid operator!");
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: `Scanner#nextDouble()` will throw an `InputMismatchException` when something except a `Double` was entered. One of the solutions would be to catch that exception and print something.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code where the input of numbers are done with below code:

```
             try {
                num1= Double.parseDouble(s.next());
                num2= Double.parseDouble(s.next());
             } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Double.parseDouble has changed specs several times, so fall through
                // gracefully
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.print("You entered text as a number: ");
                return;
             }
```